# dynamically generating controls

Tags: c#, blazor

I have a foreach loop and I need to create a button that allows the user to get the address of a specific location. The issue is when the page is generated, if you click ANY button, they all display the popover.

```
@foreach (var schedule in _schedules) {
     <BSButton Id="popover1" onclick="onclick1">@schedule.Location.NickName</BSButton>
     <BSPopover Target="popover1" IsOpen="@IsOpen1" Placement="Placement.Top">
         <BSPopoverHeader>@schedule.Location.Name</BSPopoverHeader>
         <BSPopoverBody>@schedule.Location.Address</BSPopoverBody>
     </BSPopover>
 }
```

code on top of the same page

```
@code {
bool IsOpen1 { get; set; }
void onclick1(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    IsOpen1 = !IsOpen1;
    StateHasChanged();
}
}
```

I am having trouble figuring out how to generate this type of control. I know the problem is the onclick is the same for all the controls. Even if I dynamically change the name in the onclick="@popoverTextId", how do I dynamically create the code in the **@code {}**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assum Schedule has an Id. Otherwise, improvise something.

```
 <BSButton @onclick="() => onclick1(schedule.Id)"> ... </BSButton>
    ....  IsOpen="@(schedule.Id == SelectedId)" ...

void onclick1(int scheduleId)
{
    SelectedId = scheduleId;
    //StateHasChanged();
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason for the "improvise"? I would normally pass the class @onclick="() => onclick1(schedule)" Something i'm missing?

Comment: what is SelectedId = scheduleId supposed to do? why did we comment out StateHasChanged?

Comment: `schedule.Id == SelectedId` is a condition for if this is the Selected one. I can't make a complete sample from this.

Comment: You don't need StateHasChnaged() in a simple buttonclick.

Comment: @Orak - not directly, but things could get weird when _schdules is reloaded for some reason.

Comment: Aside: always use a `@key` directive on any components/elements inside a loop to give the render tree diffing code something to identify each item.